# NSURL with \n to call a php file

Tags: php, ios, hyperlink, newline, nsurl

I'm using the following line of code to run my php file that I have on my server. the issue is that the \n causes an error and disables the php file from getting called. but when i remove the \n it works.

```
  NSString *link = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@?message=%@",link,[@"hello   world\nhello" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"]];
  NSData *resultData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]];
```

I  don't know what to do to make this work. is there anything else that i need to use instead of \n?!

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
NSString *link = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@?message=%@",link,@"hello   world\nhello"];
NSString *url = [link stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSData *resultData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

Comment: How come this is the correct answer as `[link stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];` returns `NSString` but it's declared as `NSURL`?

Comment: @graver good catch. The proper code should be `[NSURL URLWithString:[link stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
NSString *link = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@?message=hello world%@hello",link,@"\n"];
NSData *resultData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably escape the crazy characters of the parameters carried in your "`link`" URL string by using [NSString's `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding%3a).